# ActiveRecord anonymous scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I am learning about anonymous scope from watch RailsCast [video](http://railscasts.com/episodes/112-anonymous-scopes). When I try it myself, it seems like the statement:

```
scope = User.scoped
```

immediately queries the DB with SQL statement:

```
User Load (3.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`
```

Before I even have a chance to chain conditions. This is obviously very inefficient and it's not happening when the author in the video does it. What am i missing?

Also, at what point does the scope know that I am done chaining conditions and it's time to perform the query?

Comment: Have you tried chaining it to make sure it isn't simply because you haven't continued the chain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying this in the console? The problem is that if you type:

```
scope = User.scoped
```

The `console` tries to inspect the last statement and triggers the query. To avoid that, simply return something at the end:

```
scope = User.scoped; nil
```

This way the `console` inspects `nil` and nothing happens to your `scope` variable. This won't be a problem in the actual code since nobody will try to inspect it right after you define it.

Comment: Ah I see. Can you tell me at what point is scope variable actually turned into a query?

Comment: When you try to access the data (calling #all, iterating over it etc.), everything else should be lazy and return just `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

Answer (score 1):

I do not like to discourage you , but it's pretty sure , that in Rails 4 the method `scoped` is about to be deprecated . More interesting new features of the new version are discussed in [this RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/400-what-s-new-in-rails-4) .